# Shorting stock vs buying stock on margin which fee is higher?

Tags: fees, shorting-securities

I know when you buy stock on margin you need to pay a interest rate for example with IB a rate + benchmark rate.  How expensive is shorting a stock long term, is it a similar fee as buying on margin e.g. rate + benchmark rate or is it more expensive?

The stock I'm thinking about is GME.  How long would it cost to hold short a stock like this long term?

Comment: My broker will not let me short GME for obvious reasons - it is too risky. There is a not insignificant risk that I could end up owing the broker a zillion dollars.

Comment: @user253751 that probably true a year ago but I dont think the stock itself has that kind of volitility now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you short a stock, you pay a daily borrow fee (including weekends) for every day that you are short plus the two days for T+2 settlement.

The borrow rate can fluctuate daily.  It can range from 0.25% for a stodgy large cap stock to 100s of a percent a year. I have seen a few with a borrow rate of 1,000%.  The fees accrue daily and IBKR deducts the total from your account at the beginning of each month.

I can't tell you how long it would cost to hold a short position in GME because my platform is off and I don't know what the borrow rate is.  If you are with IBKR, their platform supplies this info.

Comment: I havnt checked my monthly fee yet